# intellisense fails for file added to NUnit[Lite] project in Xamarin/Mono

Tags: intellisense, code-completion, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I'm trying out Xamarin (on Mac OS X) to do some cross-platform (Mac, iOS, Android) development in Mono.  I've created a "Point" class inside a "Filament" namespace, and now I'm trying to add unit tests.

There appear to be two approaches to unit testing in the Mono world: NUnit and NUnitLite.  I've tried both (in the latter case, following [this tutorial](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/touch.unit)), with the same result, which is this:

In my unit test project, I add a link to the Point.cs file (by right-clicking the project, using 'Add...', selecting the file, and then choosing the "Add as Link" option).  In my unit test file (PointTest.cs), I add "using Filament;" to the top of the file.  But despite the fact that I can now use the Point class, and it successfully compiles, Intellisense seems completely oblivious to it -- every time I start to type "Point" it extends this to "PointTest", and when I doggedly change it back to Point, it draws it in red like an error.

In fact, the same trouble happened on my "using" line; I typed "using Filament" and it changed this to "using FilamentTestsiOS" (the namespace of my unit test project).

This is driving me nuts... but as a complete noob to Mono, Xamarin, NUnit, and NUnitLite, I'm sure I'm doing something stupid.

What's the correct way to set up a C#/Mono unit test, so that both intellisense and the compiler will recognize the classes for which I'm writing tests?